# Do you need to create new outbound changeset when components are modified?

Tags: visual-workflow, page-layout, sandbox, change-set, production

Let's say I have created an Outbound ChangeSet with a few components like Page Layouts and Lightning Flows. I haven't pushed the change set to Production yet. In the meantime, I decided to make some changes to the layouts or the flows.

Do I need to create a new ChangeSet or the old one that is still lying around in the sandbox will pick-up the changes when I finally push to production?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create a new Change Set.

Change Sets don't "snapshot" the components that are added to them until the point when the Change Set is uploaded to another org. Until that point, the Change Set just keeps a list of references to the components that *will be* uploaded.

Once you do upload the Change Set, you'd need to create a new one to capture changes subsequent to the upload. But until then, you'll always be uploading the current state of the metadata at time of upload.

Comment: Thank you David. That was my guess too (and the most logical way for things to happen) - but wanted to be 100% sure.